# Trying to link OpenGL with Makefiles

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, makefile

I am on an Intel Mac. I installed the GLEW, glfw, and glm libraries using HomeBrew. I ran the code below and got an error message, but when I removed one line calling the glClear function,

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

It gave this error.

```
g++ main.o -o main -L/usr/local/lib/ -lGLEW -lglfw
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glClear", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

When I remove that one command, the GLFW window opens and it responds to the escape key closing the window. It seems that only OpenGL commands do not work. I can't figure out why. I tried calling other OpenGL functions and every time it gave an error, but glew functions work fine.

C++ File:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);

    if(!glfwInit()){
        printf("Initialization failed");
    } else {
        printf("GLFW Works\n");
    }

    // Creates a window and an OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "GAME", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW Window.");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //glewExperimental = true; // needed for core profile
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if(err != GLEW_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW. "/*, glewGetErrorString(err)*/);
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

    glm::mat4 PerspectiveProjection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f/3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 OrthoProjection = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, 0.01f, 100.0f);

    do{
        // Swap buffers
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    } while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == false );

    // Cleanup VBO
    

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
LIB = -L/usr/local/lib/ -lGLEW -lglfw
UNI_HEADER = /usr/local/include/

ALL: main
    ./main

main: main.o
    g++ main.o -o main $(LIB)

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp -I $(UNI_HEADER)

test: test.o
    g++ test.o -o test $(LIB)

test.o: test.cpp
    g++ -c test.cpp -I $(UNI_HEADER)

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm main main.o *.o
```

Comment: Where is your GLEW initialized? `-framework OpenGL -framework GLUT` may be easier?

Comment: @Neil the library is in "/usr/local/lib" and the headers is in "/usr/local/include". At least the aliases are.

Comment: When I run a premade tutorial script in Xcode which I had to unpack from CMake, the OpenGL commands ran fine, but the libraries are in the project folder for that build.

Comment: In GLUT, something like this was required, `if((err = glewInit()) != GLEW_OK || !glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_2_0")) exit;`, don't know about GLFW.

Comment: But before I can run the executable, it returns that linking error. Like the header is connected and the GLEW library as well, but not the OpenGL functions

Comment: have you tried adding `-lGL`?

Comment: It says no library found `muse@muses-MacBook-Pro OPENGL % make
g++ main.o -o main -L/usr/local/lib/ -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL
ld: library not found for -lGL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1`

Comment: `-framework OpenGL`?

Answer (score 2):

Like Neil commented, all I had to do was add `-framework OpenGL` to my lib variable in my Makefile. So when I run the command to link the object files, it is:

```
g++ test.o -o test -L/usr/local/lib/ -lGLEW -lglfw -framework OpenGL
```

Makefile:

```
LIB = -L/usr/local/lib/ -lGLEW -lglfw -framework OpenGL
UNI_HEADER = /usr/local/include/

ALL: main
    ./main

main: main.o
    g++ main.o -o main $(LIB)

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp -I $(UNI_HEADER)

test: test.o
    g++ test.o -o test $(LIB)

test.o: test.cpp
    g++ -c test.cpp -I $(UNI_HEADER)

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm main main.o *.o
```

Comment: I would like to know what that actually does, but I only arrived at it though trial-and-error. It may be related to MacOSX being integrated with OpenGL. Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of guessing compiler flags and what libraries you need to link to, you should be using pkg-config, [as advised in GLFW's own build guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html).

> GLFW supports pkg-config, and the glfw3.pc pkg-config file is
> generated when the GLFW library is built and is installed along with
> it. A pkg-config file describes all necessary compile-time and
> link-time flags and dependencies needed to use a library. When they
> are updated or if they differ between systems, you will get the
> correct ones automatically.

Glew supports pkg-config too. Any library you make should support pkg-config too, that way it doesn't matter who uses what build system, pkg-config provides all the flags you need, *specified by people who maintain the library and/or the package*, there's no reason to ever not use this. Simply stop creating problems where there are none. You should only ever write flags manually when the library in question does not support pkg-config, better yet, you could contribute to the library by advising them to support it so you don't have to split hairs over trifle matters like this. pkg-config is not the holy grail, there's alternatives, like vcpkg, conan, you name it, but my point is, please use them. Rant over.

```
DEPENDENCIES = 'glew glfw3'

CXXFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(DEPENDENCIES))
LDLIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs $(DEPENDENCIES))

ALL: main
    ./main

main: main.o
    g++ main.o -o main $(LDLIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

test: test.o
    g++ test.o -o test $(LDLIBS)

test.o: test.cpp
    g++ -c test.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm main main.o *.o
```

This is clean, simple, and when you will want to add, I don't know, `libcurl`, the only thing you will have to do is change `DEPENDENCIES` variable to include it.

If you installed those libraries in `/usr/local`, then depending on your system configuration, you may have to

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

before running any commands depending on pkg-config. If you run these pkg-config commands and check what they return, you will also notice that you don't have to specify where to search for headers nor libraries either.